# C++, Google Tests, утечки макетных объектов и testing::Mock::AllowLeak()

Tags: c++, mock, gtest

Я пытаюсь поправить тесты (`Google Tests`), которые писал не я, и у меня есть несколько вопросов, на которые я не смог найти ответы.

Вопросы следующие:

1. Каким механизмом `Google Tests` обнаруживает утечку макетного объекта?
2. Для чего нужна функция (предположительно, функция) `testing::Mock::AllowLeak()`?
3. Есть ли разница, передавать в `ON_CALL() / EXPECT_CALL()` сырой указатель или умный?

Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там имеется глобальный реестр для таких объектов. Они заносятся в него при использовании, и убираются при разрушении. В деструкторе самого регистра подсчитываются утечки и печатается соотв. предупреждения. [из исходников](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/ba513d2c9525a7c986c115ed5d603f2cf17c6016/googlemock/src/gmock-spec-builders.cc#L586):

> A global registry holding the state of all mock objects that are alive.  A mock object is added to this registry the first time `Mock::AllowLeak()`, `ON_CALL()`, or `EXPECT_CALL()` is called on it. It is removed from the registry in the mock object's destructor.
>   `class MockObjectRegistry`